# Forcibly Refreshing NSView From ViewController (AppDelegate)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have a small view object called BackgroundView1, a subclass of **NSView**, sitting on MainMenu.xib.  The main view controller is **AppDelegate**.  This view object shows some drawing.  Anyway, I have the following code for this view object.

```
// .h
@interface BackgroundView1 : NSView

// .m
@implementation BackgroundView1

- (void)awakeFromNib {    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidBecomeKey:) name:NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object:[self window]];
}

- (void) windowDidBecomeKey:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES]; 
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

I wonder if there's any way of forcibly refreshing this view object (BackgroundView1) from AppDelegate when the user clicks on a push button?  I also have the following code in AppDelegate.

```
// AppDelegate.h
#import "BackgroundView1.h"
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject
@property (weak) BackgroundView1 *view1;

// AppDelegate.m
- (IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender {
    BackgroundView1 *view1 = [[BackgroundView1 alloc] init];
    [view1 setNeedsLayout:YES];
}
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're creating a new object, asking it to layout, and then throwing away that object. This has nothing to do with the object in your view.

First, in OS X, the property `view1` should be strong, not weak. (This is different than in iOS.)

Second, it needs to be an `IBOutlet`, and you need to wire that IBOutlet to the actual view in Interface Builder.

Third, you need to then send the message to that view:

```
[self.view1 setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

There is no reason to `alloc` another view.

It is somewhat unusual (though not unheard of) for an `NSView` to watch for its window to become key. It is more common for the `NSWindow` to keep track of this and update its views accordingly.

There are a lot of errors here that suggest you haven't worked through the introductory tutorials (or haven't understood them). I recommend starting with [Your First Mac App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just implement this lines of code in your action no need to forcibly refresh the view:-

```
     [view1 setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```